# flutter run: Error: Activity class {com.example.x/com.example.x.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: flutter, dart, smartphone

Computer: Debian Sid, Flutter 3.3.10, Dart 2.18.6
Mobile: Google Pixel 3a, GrapheneOS last update (Android 12)

When I run my app with command line or vscode, I have an error:

```
...
[ +424 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 3,9s)
[  +65 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory:
'/home/romain/documents/flutter/drissas-flutter/app_musique/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk'/app.apk
[+1147 ms] ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/aapt dump xmltree
/home/romain/documents/flutter/drissas-flutter/app_musique/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +7 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.0/aapt dump xmltree
/home/romain/documents/flutter/drissas-flutter/app_musique/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1f
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="12" (Raw: "12")
               A: package="com.example.app_musique" (Raw: "com.example.app_musique")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1f
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xc
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x10
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1f
               E: uses-permission (line=15)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: application (line=17)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="app_musique" (Raw: "app_musique")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.app.Application" (Raw: "android.app.Application")                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw:
                 "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: activity (line=23)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.app_musique.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.app_musique.MainActivity")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: meta-data (line=38)
                     A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme" (Raw:
                     "io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme")
                     A: android:resource(0x01010025)=@0x7f0a0001
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: uses-library (line=56)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.extensions" (Raw: "androidx.window.extensions")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
                 E: uses-library (line=59)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="androidx.window.sidecar" (Raw: "androidx.window.sidecar")
                   A: android:required(0x0101028e)=(type 0x12)0x0
[   +1 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on Pixel 3a.
[        ] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D shell am force-stop com.example.app_musique
[ +137 ms] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D shell pm list packages com.example.app_musique
[  +79 ms] Installing APK.
[   +1 ms] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
[        ] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D install -t -r
/home/romain/documents/flutter/drissas-flutter/app_musique/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk
[+3324 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                    Success
[        ] Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk... (completed in 3,3s)
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D shell echo -n ce3a5b315fa9f958146cb18d5103c9f27f04354c
> /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.app_musique.sha1
[  +63 ms] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +97 ms] --------- beginning of system
           01-03 10:26:20.118 W/ActivityManager( 1214): Skipping broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
           flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.example.app_musique (has extras) }: user 11 and its parent (if any) are stopped
[  +13 ms] executing: /home/romain/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s 05SAY1Y50D shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c
android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points
true com.example.app_musique/com.example.app_musique.MainActivity
[ +159 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000
cmp=com.example.app_musique/.MainActivity (has extras) }

                    Error type 3
                    Error: Activity class {com.example.app_musique/com.example.app_musique.MainActivity} does not exist.
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
```

I haven't programmed in 1 or 2 months. I have tested: System update, flutter update, GrapheneOS update. Tested with my Google Pixel 6 is good but my setup for dev is with my Google Pixel 3a.

An idea? thank you!

Comment: I am facing the same issue while debugging flutter project in android studio. But, if I try to build from the android project, it is running successfully.